# Twitter 1.1, Authentication and Display of Search Results

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I am confused about this upcoming Twitter API 1.1 change and how to re-implement functionality like that that used to be provided by jquery widgets like http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/ and http://thomasbillenstein.com/jTweetsAnywhere/.

I have been able to get linq-to-twitter to do a search using the ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer to at least get most of the information into a GridView, but this will re-use the same tokens (the ones belonging to the application) over and over, and will very quickly burn through 450 requests in 15 minutes when deployed to a live site with hundreds/thousands of active users...

In addition, for display I'd rather be able to re-use one of the basic jquery plugins out there, so it seems I'd have to point the jquery ajax call to a local page method or web service to make the server-side call for me...then if I were using linq-to-twitter I'd have to mash together the search results into an anonymous object and JSON serialize it back to the browser...right?

In addition, to solve the rate-limiting issue, it seems like Twitter would like me to make these search requests on behalf of my users, but that will require sending them through the oAuth authorization workflow, and then having to store their tokens somewhere to use every time they load a page that shows the "twitter feed".  Right?

Finally, part of the functionality built into the existing application is the ability to store a list of tweet ids and twitter user ids and strip those out of the results (if they are offensive, etc).

My brain tells me that there is no way that a simple task such as "show me all tweets with #whatever in them, except for tweet ids 1111212, and 1356346" will require everything I describe above...

What am I missing here?

**Edit to Clarify Question**
If all queries to Twitter's 1.1 search API must be authenticated, and using ApplicationOnly oAuth authentication is not an option due to rate-limiting, and we don't want to force users through oAuth to capture their tokens, how are we expected to show lists of tweets from the search API in an auto-update jquery-like fashion?

Comment: This is like 5 questions built into one with no code. What do you expect here?

Comment: I'll try to clarify it, the only code I could post would be the example ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer code which I think would only clutter the question I was trying to ask even more.

Comment: As it stands, this isn't a good fit for Q&A format, mostly because it's objective at best, and full of theory-gramming. Tackle 1 issue at a time, as we're not going to develop a 5 page long post address every issue you have. Also, show the leg work you've gone through to attempt to fix these issues. If you've made no attempt, it sounds like you need a developer.

Comment: As to your clarification question:  **You are not expected to do it.**

Answer (score 0):

The only option I've found is Embedded Timelines (unless you want to build your own server-side solution with caching, etc):

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines